# Setgid bis is *not* set on a new directory when ACLs are enabled

Tags: linux, samba, setgid, mkdir

I'm struggling with ACLs on Linux. In my setup, I need to inherit both setgid bit and my ACLs when creating new directories. The ACLs are inherited as expected. The new directory has got all ACLs the parent directory has. Unfortunately, the setgid bit is not inherited to the new subfolder. Has anyone came across that issue? Might it be default Linux behavior?

Cheers, flip

Answer (score 0):

I figured the reason out. I forget to mention that the directory is owned by root:root. It seems that this is desired behavior. Thus, if a directories primary group is root, the setgid bit seems to be ignored by the kernel when ACLs are active.
If I use a different group, e.g. adm, the setgid bit works as expected.